# if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) is returning false

Tags: android-fragments, android-imageview

I am working on a very basic app which captures a photo using the phone's camera and sets it up on the ImageView. But the code is not entering the if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) statement. I understood this by using Log inside the if statement. Any idea how I can resolve this? Here is the onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Log.v("cam"," resultCode");
        Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        bmp=(Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        button1.setText("Take Another");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**first of all**

- Check that u have all the necessary permission in the manifest file for capturing the image and where you're storing that image that folder access.

Check it out for more reference. [for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

Answer (score -1):

Try This ... It works for Me..

```
if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
        Uri path = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),path);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```